# Adding auto incremented column on select join statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have requirement to create an auto incremented id based on certain join condition. I have two tables each having identity column. Primary table would have relationship with the secondary table on "trxid" column. Below is the sample data

```
declare @t1 table (trxid int,data1 varchar(100), data2 varchar(100))
declare @m table (mid int, trxid int, mname varchar(100), mdate date)

insert into @t1
select 1,'Test1','Test1'
union all
select 2,'Test2','Test2'

insert into @m
select 1,1,'Stage Gate1',GETDATE()
union all
select 2,1,'Stage Gate2',GETDATE()
union all
select 3,1,'Stage Gate3',GETDATE()
union all
select 4,1,'Stage Gate4',GETDATE()
union all
select 5,1,'Stage Gate5',GETDATE()
union all
select 6,1,'Stage Gate6',GETDATE()
union all
select 7,2,'Stage Gate1',GETDATE()
union all
select 8,2,'Stage Gate2',GETDATE()
union all
select 9,2,'Stage Gate3',GETDATE()
union all
select 10,2,'Stage Gate4',GETDATE()
union all
select 11,2,'Stage Gate5',GETDATE()
union all
select 12,2,'Stage Gate6',GETDATE()
union all
select 13,2,'Stage Gate7',GETDATE()
```

Result with below statement

```
select t.trxid,m.mid,t.data1,t.data2,m.mname,m.mdate from @t1 t inner join @m m on(t.trxid=m.trxid)

   trxid       mid         data1   data2   mname           mdate
----------- ----------- ------- ------- --------------- ----------
1           1           Test1   Test1   Stage Gate1     2018-06-07
1           2           Test1   Test1   Stage Gate2     2018-06-07
1           3           Test1   Test1   Stage Gate3     2018-06-07
1           4           Test1   Test1   Stage Gate4     2018-06-07
1           5           Test1   Test1   Stage Gate5     2018-06-07
1           6           Test1   Test1   Stage Gate6     2018-06-07
2           7           Test2   Test2   Stage Gate1     2018-06-07
2           8           Test2   Test2   Stage Gate2     2018-06-07
2           9           Test2   Test2   Stage Gate3     2018-06-07
2           10          Test2   Test2   Stage Gate4     2018-06-07
2           11          Test2   Test2   Stage Gate5     2018-06-07
2           12          Test2   Test2   Stage Gate6     2018-06-07
2           13          Test2   Test2   Stage Gate7     2018-06-07
```

Expected result is

```
trxid       id          mid         data1   data2   mname           mdate
----------- ----------- ----------- ------- ------- --------------- ----------
1           1           1           Test1   Test1   Stage Gate1     2018-06-07
1           2           2           Test1   Test1   Stage Gate2     2018-06-07
1           3           3           Test1   Test1   Stage Gate3     2018-06-07
1           4           4           Test1   Test1   Stage Gate4     2018-06-07
1           5           5           Test1   Test1   Stage Gate5     2018-06-07
1           6           6           Test1   Test1   Stage Gate6     2018-06-07
2           1           7           Test2   Test2   Stage Gate1     2018-06-07
2           2           8           Test2   Test2   Stage Gate2     2018-06-07
2           3           9           Test2   Test2   Stage Gate3     2018-06-07
2           4           10          Test2   Test2   Stage Gate4     2018-06-07
2           5           11          Test2   Test2   Stage Gate5     2018-06-07
2           6           12          Test2   Test2   Stage Gate6     2018-06-07
2           7           13          Test2   Test2   Stage Gate7     2018-06-07
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you don't need to persist this ID and then generate new unique incremental numbers based on the persisted data, you can use window functions to generate a `row_number` for each group of your data:

```
select t.trxid
      ,m.mid
      ,row_number() over (partition by t.trxid order by m.mid) as id
      ,t.data1
      ,t.data2
      ,m.mname
      ,m.mdate
from @t1 t
    inner join @m m
        on(t.trxid = m.trxid)
```

---

If you need to base this on data that you have already saved to a table elsewhere, your query will need to be more complex.

Comment: Fastest windowed function in the west 